# How to sort an array in node.js based on time in milliseconds using Redis database

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to sort an array which contains Id and Time,based on time(milliseconds).

```
Map.sort(function(a,b){return a.Time-b.Time});
for (keys in Map) {
    multi.hgetall(Map[key].id+':List');                     
}
multi.exec(function(err,data){                       
        res.send(data);
});
```

Its not displaying any data.There are 3 Ids in that array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is `res` in your code. And even if you name the variable `keys`, you'll get the array indexes in this sentence:

```
for(keys in Map){...}
```

Try something like this, using a `forEach` iterator:

```
Map=[{'id':'a', 'Time':90}, {'id':'c', 'Time':30}, {'id':'b', 'Time':66}]

Map.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
    multi.hgetall(item.id + ':List');
});
multi.exec(function(err, data){                       
    console.log('data', data);
});
```

It should print some data if the keys `a:List`, `b:List` and `c:List` exist in your redis database.